# Best way to convert an ASP.NET MVC view to Angular

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I'm redesigning an existing ASP.net mvc page, which displays multiple client objects on a single page.
The reason why, is so the page can save all the clients/edits on a single click.
However as I wrote this 18 months ago it feels like their should be a better way to do it, as I have to use a FormBinder to map\save the objects, which is not pretty.

For example, I've started to use bootstrap tabs, each tab is a client and contains the details

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">

        @foreach (var client in Model.Clients)
        {
            <li><a data-target="#@client.ClientId" data-toggle="tab" href="#@client.ClientId"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> @client.Name</a></li>

        }

    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">

            @foreach (var client in Model.Clients)
            {
                <div class="tab-pane" id="@client.ClientId">
                    <div class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="@client.Name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => client.Name, new { @class = "form-control", tabindex = "1"})
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            }


        </div>
```

Is their a better, easier way to do this?
Ideally I don't want to use a form binder as well?

Thoughts? Examples?

Comment: Is your question on the best way to convert a standard mvc/razor view to Angular?

Answer (score 0):

I will say that as far as load time goes, Angular is going to help you a lot here.  In your example, you will be loading the html for all of those tags once for each client.  Angular would only load it once as a template, and duplicate the html on the client.

The angular equivalent would be something like this...

```
<div class="tab-content" ng-controller='ClientCtrl">
    <div class="tab-pane">
        <div class="form-horizontal" role="form">
            <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="client in clients">
                <label for="clientName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input name='clientName' type='text' class='form-control' tabindex='1'>{{client.Name}}</input>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Granted, you'd have to do some work to implement the controller, but it's easy enough to do.

The benefits are that the scope is handling all of your ID's, so there is no need to keep track of any of that yourself.  In some ways Angular is a difficult transition to learn, but once you do, it makes managing the code SO much easier.